# Directory lister program is faulty , C++

Tags: c++

I am making a program to collect directory and user folder names , keep in mind that I am doing this as a hobby although I might take Computer Science next year if I am lucky.

Language : C++

IDE : Code Blocks

Problem : It is suppose to create a text file with a list of files in the directories below , but when I run it , it does not do that , what it does is nothing.

Code :

```
void directory_lister() // List folders in respective directories.
{
    string dir_hos = " ";
    int cycle = 0;
    string dir_program = "C:\\Program Files\\";
    string dir_program32 = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\";
    string dir_users = "C:\\Users\\";

    while (cycle < 3){

        if(dir_hos != dir_program){
            dir_hos = dir_program;
            cycle++;

            DIR *dir = NULL;
            struct dirent *drnt = NULL;
            opendir(dir_hos.c_str());

            while((drnt = readdir(dir))) // Faulty code #1.
            {
                w_file("directorylist.txt",drnt->d_name);
            }
            closedir(dir);

            cout << cycle;
        }else if(dir_hos != dir_program32){
            dir_hos = dir_program32;
            cycle++;

            DIR *dir = NULL;
            struct dirent *drnt = NULL;
            opendir(dir_hos.c_str());

            while((drnt = readdir(dir)))  // Faulty code #2.
            {
                w_file("directorylist.txt",drnt->d_name);
            }
            closedir(dir);

            cout << cycle;
        }else if(dir_hos == dir_users){
            dir_hos = dir_users;
            cycle++;

            DIR *dir = NULL;
            struct dirent *drnt = NULL;
            opendir(dir_hos.c_str());

            while((drnt = readdir(dir)))  // Faulty code #3.
            {
                w_file("directorylist.txt",drnt->d_name);
            }
            closedir(dir);

            cout << cycle;
        }

    }

    return;
}

int main(){
    directory_lister();
    return 0;
}
```

Also w_file function is this :

```
void w_file(string filename_s, char * content)
{
    // Change string to const char *
    const char * filename_cc = filename_s.c_str();

    // Writing File Code
    ofstream file;
    file.open(filename_cc,ios::app);
    file << content << endl;
    file.close();
    return;
}
```

---

Compiler output :

Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

---

Faulty code #1,#2,#3 :

Before this I do not have extra brackets , e.g while(drnt = readdir(dir)) , but the compiler gives me 3 warning about not enough brackets (compiled successfully but does not work) , so I add them but it still does not work.

I also tried using "==" instead of "=" but it hanged the program and it crashed. Before it crash it managed to make "directories.txt" .

---

Others :

I think there are other codes that I have not properly written but I can't figure it out since I am bad at programming. Can you guys help me fix it? I am sure I will learn something out of this . Thank you!

---

On another note :

I am not particularly good at using dirent.h , every time I use it I am so blur , I usually look up examples and copy the simplest ones to use (I am ashamed but I am very confused when reading the documentation).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read **[How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**  At least leave us with a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: @Spera (1) define "does not work", provide detailed description of desired behavior vs observed behavior, (2) provide a code example that we could compile and/or run to reproduce the problem (hint: in order to build a program you need function `main()`), (3) provide all relevant console output by copying it into your post (as it is, verbatim, not your interpretation of it)

Comment: @Drop , Done , done and done .

Comment: @Spera And your observations from debugging are actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am following the steps in the link that you sent me , but I am afraid I am running out of time , and also I think I have been compiling it in debug mode. I might get back tommorow but i can use my phone. Also , I've tried the rubber duck way but I can't seem to see any problem , I think it is because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Spera _Rubber duck_ is a really promising approach. You might need to talk to her again :).

Comment: Peter told me why it is not working , even though I previously do not know that you need to store the value of opendir in a variable to pass it to readdir , I feel like it is a very simple mistake. Oh well , thank you for the links , apparently I can't copy your name on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument supplied to `readdir()` is supposed to be a value previously returned by `opendir()` - supplying a null pointer as you are causes an error.

The value returned by `opendir()` is never stored in a variable - which means it is immediately discarded, and certainly never passed to `readdir()`.

It is usually a good idea to check the return values of functions.   For example, `opendir()` returns a null pointer on error.

I haven't looked closely enough to determine if there are other problems ....   but fixing the problems I have identified will be educational for you anyway.

Comment: Ah , So I need to store opendir() in dir , dir = opendir(); Thank you very much sir.

Comment: I will try the fix as soon as possible Thank you very much sir .